# How to make animated container have dynamic height

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a expand-able container that have a specific height of 150 when it shrink and only show maximal 2 line of text.

But when the user click on the container it will expand to height of depending on the text if the text from the database is 10 line the height have to be 10 line but when the max text is 20 the height need to adjust to 20 line.

Can I achieve it using animatedContainer or animatedSize ?

Comment: Can you include a minimal widget that will reproduce the same issue ?

Comment: what is that ??

Comment: [readmore](https://pub.dev/packages/readmore) Is it helpful to you?

Comment: Check about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use an animated container..

```dart
bool widgetExpanded = false;

InkWell
(
 onTap :(){
    setState((){
      widgetExpanded = !widgetExpanded;
    });
  }
child : AnimatedContainer(
  height : widgetExpanded ? 300:150, //<-- optional. Only if you wish to add height
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  child: Text("Some big text here", style: TextStyle(
  maxLines: widgetExpanded? null: 2,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
 ))
)
)
```

Also please take a look at expansion tile
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html

Comment: so I cant just not specify the height for the animated container ?

Comment: Of course you can. Add a height to the Animated container. But when it's expanded you have to specify another height. It won't dynamically for the text size. You may take a look at expansion tile for this behaviour

Comment: I don't think the expansion tile is fit for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExpansionTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) to create that animation, it is expanded to your text or any widget as you like.